# Rails / ActiveRecord: Set datetime to null if checkbox is not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got posts that have an optional "expire_at" datetime.

I'm trying to save this datetime from my form **if** a "custom_expire_at" checkbox is checked.  If it is not checked, the datetime should be set to NULL.

I've tried trashing the expire_at parameters if the checkbox value is not there:

```
# Delete expiration dates if box is not checked
if params[:item][:custom_expire_at]
  params[:item].delete(:custom_expire_at)
else
  params[:item].delete(:expire_at)
end
```

However, expire_at is multi-parameter:

```
"expire_at(1i)"=>"2011", "expire_at(2i)"=>"2", "expire_at(3i)"=>"10", "expire_at(4i)"=>"21", "expire_at(5i)"=>"32"
```

Trying to avoid completely destroying this datetime select via jQuery -- would much rather pop it out of the params.

In summary:
1) How can I strip out these parameters if I don't want them?
2) even if I managed to strip out expire_at, I don't know how to set a value back to NULL.  If I set expire_at to nil, my model will ignore the update.

```
  def ensure_expire_at_has_a_value
    self.expire_at ||= nil
  end
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the multi-parameter you could use delete_if to delete all expire_at parameters:

```
params.delete_if{ |key, value| key.match(/^expire_at/) }
```

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks.  Any idea how to set my datetime back to NULL?

Comment: You can probably do params[:item][:expire_at] = nil to force this to happen when you call update_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in your model instead. Create an `attr_accessor` for `custom_expire_at`. Ensure that your form is hooked up to it. Then, create a `before_validation` method which does this:

self.expire_at = null if custom_expire_at != '1'

BTW, you're checking against `'1'` because that's what checkboxes send back.